# Why does my symfony demo install with an old version of symfony?

Tags: symfony

I installed the symfony demo but it installs using an older version, I'm not sure why?

Earlier I installed an older version of the demo using command:

```
composer create-project symfony/symfony-demo bp3 1.1.1
```

This works fine and installs to directory bp3, runs fine, uses Symfony 3.3.9 (pops up a box in the bottom right on the Dev toolbar in red with the Symfony logo says sf 3.3.9 and when you hover says it is out of support).

Then I tried to install the latest version of the demo using command:

```
symfony new bp4 --demo
```

I assumed it would install the latest version of the demo to directly bp4, but when I launch the site in directory bp4 it is running on Symfony 3.3.6. (pops up a box in the bottom right on the Dev toolbar in red with the Symfony logo says sf 3.3.6 and when you hover says it is out of support).

- Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
- Symfony CLI version v4.14.4
- Composer version 1.10.6 (installed globally)
- PHP 7.2.11 (cli)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `create-project symfony/symfony-demo project-folder`.
If you want to use latest version of Symfony install PHP 7.3.5 or latest (I'm use PHP 7.4.2)